# Where can be found posix path specification?

Tags: path, posix, specifications

I want my application be able to handle any posix-compatible file path. But the only thing I've found after a long time of googling is [this bnf](http://www.gridlab.org/WorkPackages/wp-1/Doc/C-Manual/node273.html). Doesn't look like official and trustful source.

Should I trust the information at the link above? Where can be found more or less official specification?

Answer (score 3):

Definition of [pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266)

Pathname [resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11)

The grammar that you linked above, looks good.